# list background on hover not entirely covered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some kind of a navigation bar with an unsorted list and have list items with graphics in them but whenever hovering over an item the background color doesn't cover the whole area or there is a bit of space inbetween each item..

Comment: Unrelated to the gaps, you might also want to look into using SVG graphics or an icon font. That way your icons will look great even on high-res screens and when the user bumps up the page zoom.

Comment: Can I use svg files as content declaration in the css?

Comment: Yes: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/. I'd look at using an icon font personally: incredibly simple once set up, and you can easily apply styling (font-size, text-shadow etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gaps that you're seeing there are caused by whitespace in your markup. Unlike floats, `inline-block` will actually respect whitespace in your HTML. The simplest solution therefore is to either add empty comments or just ensure that each `<li>` item has no space between it, like this:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><div class="refresh"></div></li><li><div class="settings"></div></li><li><div class="s_res"></div></li><li><div class="h_res"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Check out [this CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for a more in-depth explanation and other alternative fixes.

Nathan Lee's solution is one option (replacing `inline-block` with `table-cell`) but you should be aware that there are other consequences of that change (lack of IE7 support if you care about that, but also differences in `vertical-align` etc).

If you can't amend the markup, then a negative margin will achieve what you're after. However, that `-4px` is actually down to the font in use, so might need to vary slightly. It always feels like a bit of a hack. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/Wt4hP/) for an example of why this is more fragile than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.
Just replace the below css with yours.

```
ul#navbar li {
    border-right: 2px solid #FF9000;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YDgM3/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
margin-left:-4px;
```

to your

```
ul#navbar li
```